# «Досталь» і «недосталь»

Tags: нормативність

Щойно з подивом помітив, що в [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/) немає слів «досталь» і «недосталь». Немає слова «досталь» і у виданих перших томах [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index).

Як можна це пояснити? Хіба ці слова не є нормативними? Чому?

Додаткове питання: Як можна аргументувати написання «недосталь» разом (а не «не досталь»)? Так, у Грінченка саме [досталь](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/13637-dostal.html#show_point) і [недосталь](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/32291-nedostal.html#show_point) (разом з *не*) — але в Грінченка багато слів відрізняються від сучасних в написанні (того ж нормативного «вдосталь» там нема).

Додаткове питання 2: Якими частинами мови є «досталь» і «недосталь»? Мені особисто вони здаються прислівниками (або невизначено-кількісними числівниками, як от: декілька, багато, мало). Але в Грінченка (а за ним і сумнозвісному ВТССУМ) «недосталь» вважається іменником (синонімом до «недостача»). Чи це так — чи він має обидва значення (іменник і кількісно-означальний прислівник / невизначено-кількісний числівник) — чи в сучасній мові це лише прислівник/числівник?

Comment: Особисто я використовую лише "вдосталь". Окремо "досталь" якось не зустрічав...

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, а мені воно якось само на язик спадає. А як з «не»? Теж частіше «не вдосталь» кажете?

Comment: Недостатньо/замало/обмаль залежно від того, що треба підкреслити. Але це лише я особисто. )

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, мені воно спало на думку, коли я думав пофіксити «у мене *немає достатньо* часу для цієї відповідальної і корисної справи». Тут, як на мене, або «у мене немає достатньо**ї** *кількості* часу», або «у мене н̶е̶м̶а̶є̶ недостатньо/замало/обмаль/недосталь/не вдосталь часу» — але на думку мені тоді спало «недосталь». Поліз у СУМ подивитися, як воно пишеться (разом чи окремо) — і опа.

Comment: У цьому випадку я б взагалі написав "На жаль, мені бракує часу".

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, та я хотів щонайменше змінювати (ну, типу, залишити більшість слів/основ як є і на своїх позиціях). Ну, це взагалі оф-топік. Питання, чому його в таких значих словниках немає — невже воно справді застаріле?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54525/discussion-between-kyrylo-yatsenko-and-sasha).

Comment: [переношу мою вчорашню репліку з "Відповіді" сюди в "Коментарі"]

За Грінченком, "досталь" — це діалектна форма (з Черкащини).

Загальновживане слово — "удосталь" = "вдосталь", а ще кажуть — "доволі".

Comment: > Коментар від Sasha: "Тобто «досталь» не було нормативним навіть у Грінченка, отже не є нормативним і зараз — я правильно Вас розумію? А як щодо інших питань: про написання разом/окремо з «не» і про частину мови? "

Так, саме це я мав на увазі. У сучасному мовленні та письмі я слова "досталь" взагалі не зустрічав, чи не пригадую.

Щодо ж "недосталь", то, як ви слушно зауважили, у Грінченка це окреме слово, іменник із значенням, що відповідає російському "недостача", тобто там воно не є негативною формою прислівника "досталь", і це, гадаю, знімає додаткове питання щодо разом/окремо.

Comment: @QuaesitorVeritatem, а «недосталь» Ви теж у сучасному мовленні/письмі не зустрічали? Бо мені в одному тексті хотілося поставити саме «недосталь» (а «не вдосталь» здавалося зовсім не тим і занадто довгим).

Comment: @Sasha, саме так, _не_ зустрічав також і "недосталь" (хотів був додати це ще в попередньому коментарі, але не влізало... :) ). В значенні російського "недостача", залежно від контексту я б ужив "нестача", "нестаток", "недостатність", "брак", "дефіцит". В значенні, зворотньому до "удосталь"/"доволі"/"досить"/"достатньо" могли б іти відповідні "не", коли окремо, коли й разом. До речі, у Грінченка є й прислівник "недосить" одним словом. А що то у Вас був за текст, який контекст?

Comment: @QuaesitorVeritatem, та просто хотів виправити помилку в дописі користувача: «у мене *немає достатньо* часу для…» (по-моєму: або «…немає достатньо*ї кількості*…» або (без «немає») «у мене недостатньо/брак/замало часу для…» — але не «у мене немає достатньо…»). Але з язика в мене тоді чомусь зіскочило «у мене недо́сталь часу…» (мені воно тоді здалося не просто нормативним, а значно природнішим за інші варіанти; мабуть, помітив колись у дитинстві в літературі і запам'яталося). Але коли я поліз у СУМ-11, щоб про всяк випадок переконатися, що пишеться разом — не побачив і дуже здивувався.

Comment: @QuaesitorVeritatem, ну, я вже зрозумів, що це, мабуть, моя помилка, і воно не зовсім нормативне.

Comment: @Sasha, повністю згоден. Ту фразу "у мене немає достатньо часу для…" я б виправив на "мені бракує часу для ..." - дуже близько до одного з Ваших варіантів. Цікаво, що Ваш імпровізований перший варіант "у мене недо́сталь часу…" мені теж здається досить природним: якщо б зустрів десь просто у тексті то, мабуть, сприйняв би як цілком нормальну фразу... ;)

Answer (score 1):

ВДО́СТАЛЬ (УДО́СТАЛЬ), присл. У достатній мірі, в необхідній кількості. Удосталь задовольнятимуться потреби всіх верств населення у високоякісних товарах широкого споживання (Програма КПРС, 1961, 81); Жирна баранина парувала поруч на дошці, а Горпина різала її, доглядаючи, щоб усім було вдосталь (Зінаїда Тулуб, Людолови, I, 1957, 140); 
//  ірон. Дуже багато. В неблизьку пустилися [гості] путь і, вдосталь наковтавшись степової порохняви, витираються тепер хусточками (Олесь Гончар, Таврія.., 1957, 643).

Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 1, 1970. — Стор. 313.

Comment: Так, дякую. Але я питав саме про варіанти «досталь» і «недосталь». Які згадані в Грінченка і, на моє особисте відчуття, є не менш звичними, ніж «вдосталь (удосталь)», але чомусь відсутні в «Словнику української мови».